# Representing Types And Occurrences: (so) easy to understand, (so) difficult to code

Tags: haskell, types, linguistics

A brief introduction to the types and occurrences through examples.

> Ex1. `abbacb`
>
> `a`, `b`, `c` are the types.
>
> `a` occurres 2 times; `b` occurres 3 times; `c` occurres 1 times.

This can be represented more concisely as `[('a',2),('b',3),('c',1)]` (Indeed, the order doesn't matter).

> Ex2. `abbacb`
>
> `ab`, `bb`, `ba`, `ac`, `cb` are sequences of types
>
> Each sequence occurs only once.

This can be represented as `[("ab",1),("bb",1),("ba",1),("ac",1),("cb",1)]`

The following graphical structure has the same informative content of the previous two:

```
('a',2)          -- 'a'  occurs 2 times
     ('b',1)     -- "ab" occurs 1 times
     ('c',1)     -- "ac" occurs 1 times
('b',2)          -- 'b'  occurs 2 times
     ('a',1)     -- "ba" occurs 1 times
     ('b',1)     -- "bb" occurs 1 times
('c',1)          -- 'c'  occurs 1 times
     ('b',1)     -- "cb" occurs 1 times
```

In Haskell: `[(('a',2),[('b',1),('c',1)]),(('b',2),[('a',1),('b',1)]),(('c',1),[('b',1)])]`

For occurrences of sequences of 3 elements:

```
('a',2)              -- 'a'   occurs 2 times
     ('b',1)         -- "ab"  occurs 1 times
          ('b',1)    -- "abb" occurs 1 times
     ('c',1)         -- "ac"  occurs 1 times
          ('b',1)    -- "acb" occurs 1 times
...
```

In Haskell:

```
[
    (('a',2), [(('b',1),[('b',1)]),(('c',1),[('b',1)])]),
    (('b',2), [(('a',1),[('c',1)]),(('b',1),[('a',1)])])
]
```

with type `[((Char, Int), [((Char, Int), [(Char, Int)])])]`

Even considering only the sequences of two and three elements, the comprehensibility of the graphical representation is much greater than that in Haskell.

In addition, lists are not very efficient, so I used the `Data.Map` library and consequently a slightly different representation.

The following examples are based on Pi's digits. Interesting results can be obtained using the words of a novel.

**My questions are**:

1. Functions dedicated to the sequences of the three types are very complicated. It is possible to *drastically simplify* them?
2. I cannot even imagine how it is possible to generalize the functions for *sequences of arbitrary length*. Someone has an idea of how it could be done?
3. Using the following data type recursion should be easier to implement:

   ```
   data TuplesTypesOccurences a = L (M.Map a Int) | B  (M.Map a (Int,TuplesTypesOccurences a))
   ```

   In this way however does not lose access to all of the functions in `Data.Map` library?

   ```
   import qualified Data.Map as M
   import Data.List (sortBy)

   piDigits = "31415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679821480865132823066470938446095505822317253594081284811174502841027019385211055596446229489549303819644288109756659334461284756"

   type TypesOccurrences a = M.Map a Int

   toTypeOccurrences :: Ord k => [k] -> TypesOccurrences k -> TypesOccurrences k  
   toTypeOccurrences [] mp = mp
   toTypeOccurrences (x:xs) mp = toTypeOccurrences xs $ M.insertWith (+) x 1 mp
   -- ex. toTypeOccurrences piDigits M.empty

   pprintTO :: Show a => TypesOccurrences a -> IO ()
   pprintTO = mapM_ putStrLn . map (\(xs,n) -> show xs ++ "  " ++ (show n)). sortBy (\x y -> compare (snd y) (snd x)) . M.toList
   -- ex. pprintTO . M.filter (> 22) . toTypeOccurrences piDigits $ M.empty

   type Seq2TypeOccurrences a = M.Map a (Int,TypesOccurrences a)

   toSQ2TO :: Ord a => [a] -> Seq2TypeOccurrences a -> Seq2TypeOccurrences a
   toSQ2TO []       mp = mp
   toSQ2TO [x]      mp = mp
   toSQ2TO (x:y:xs) mp = toSQ2TO (y:xs) $
     case M.lookup x mp of
       Nothing       -> M.insert x (1,M.singleton y 1) mp
       Just (_,mp2) -> case M.lookup y mp2 of
           Nothing -> M.update (\(n,mp2) -> Just (n+1,M.insert y 1 mp2)) x mp
           Just _  -> M.update (\(n,mp2) -> Just (n+1,M.update (\m -> Just (m+1)) y mp2)) x mp
   -- ex. toSQ2TO piDigits M.empty

   pprintSQ2TO :: Show a => Seq2TypeOccurrences a -> IO ()
   pprintSQ2TO = mapM_ putStrLn . map (\(x,(n,mp)) -> "(" ++ (show x) ++ "," ++ (show n) ++ ")\n\t" ++ (drop 2 . concatMap (("\n\t" ++) . show) . M.toList $ mp)) . M.toList
   -- ex. pprintSQ2TO (toSQ2TO piDigits  M.empty)

   greaterThanSQ2TO :: Ord a => Int -> Seq2TypeOccurrences a -> Seq2TypeOccurrences a
   greaterThanSQ2TO n =   M.filter (\(_,mp2) -> not . M.null $ mp2) . M.map (\(o,mp2) -> (o,M.filter (> n) mp2)) . M.filter (\(m,mp) -> m > n)
   -- ex. pprintSQ2TO . greaterThanSQ2TO 4 . toSQ2TO piDigits $ M.empty

   descSortSQ2TO :: Ord a => Seq2TypeOccurrences a -> [([a], Int)]
   descSortSQ2TO = sortBy (\xs ys -> compare (snd ys) (snd xs)) . concatMap (\(x,ys) -> zipWith (\x (y,n) -> ([x,y],n)) (repeat x) ys ) . map (\(x,(_,mp2)) -> (x,M.toList mp2)) . M.toList
   -- mapM_ print . descSortSQ2TO . greaterThanSQ2TO 4 . toSQ2TO piDigits $ M.empty

   unionSQ2TO :: Ord a => Seq2TypeOccurrences a -> Seq2TypeOccurrences a -> Seq2TypeOccurrences a
   unionSQ2TO = M.unionWith (\(n1,mp1) (n2,mp2) -> (n1+n2, M.unionWith (+) mp1 mp2))

   type Seq3TypeOccurrences a = M.Map a (Int,Seq2TypeOccurrences a)

   toSQ3TO :: Ord k => [k] -> Seq3TypeOccurrences k -> Seq3TypeOccurrences k
   toSQ3TO []    mp = mp
   toSQ3TO [x]   mp = mp
   toSQ3TO [x,y] mp = mp
   toSQ3TO (x:y:z:xs) mp = toSQ3TO (y:z:xs) $
     case M.lookup x mp of
       Nothing -> M.insert x (1,M.singleton y (1,M.singleton z 1)) mp
       Just (_,mp2) -> case M.lookup y mp2 of
          Nothing -> M.update (\(n,mp2) -> Just (n+1,M.insert y (1,M.singleton z 1) mp2)) x mp
          Just (m,kns3)  -> case M.lookup z kns3 of
               Nothing -> M.update (\(n,_) -> Just (n+1,M.update (\(m,mp3) -> Just (m+1,M.insert z 1    mp3)) y mp2)) x mp
               Just _  -> M.update (\(n,_) -> Just (n+1,M.update (\(m,mp3) -> Just (m+1,M.update (Just . (+1)) z mp3)) y mp2)) x mp
   -- ex. toSQ3TO piDigits M.empty

   pprint3 :: Show a => Seq3TypeOccurrences a -> IO ()
   pprint3 = mapM_ putStrLn . map (\(x,(n,mp)) -> "(" ++ (show x) ++ "," ++ (show n) ++ ")" ++ (concatMap (\(x2,(n2,mp2)) -> "\n\t(" ++ (show x2) ++ "," ++ (show n2) ++ ")" ++ (f mp2)) . M.toList $ mp)) . M.toList
     where
     f = concatMap (\(x,n) -> "\n\t\t(" ++ (show x) ++ "," ++ (show n) ++ ")") . M.toList
   -- pprint3 . toSQ3TO piDigits $ M.empty  

   pprint3B :: Show a => Seq3TypeOccurrences a -> IO ()
   pprint3B = mapM_ putStrLn . map (\(xs,n) -> show xs ++ "  " ++ (show n)) . concatMap (\(xs,mp) -> zipWith (\ys (z,n) -> (ys ++ [z],n)) (repeat xs) mp) . concatMap (\(x,mp) -> zipWith (\y (z,mp2) -> ([y,z],mp2)) (repeat x) mp) . map (\(x,(_,mp)) -> (x, map (\(y,(_,mp2)) -> (y, M.toList mp2)) $ M.toList mp)) . M.toList
   -- pprint3B . toSQ3TO piDigits $ M.empty 

   greaterThan3Q2TO :: Ord a => Int -> Seq3TypeOccurrences a ->  Seq3TypeOccurrences a
   greaterThan3Q2TO n = M.filter (\(_,mp) -> not . M.null $ mp)
     . M.map (\(m,mp) -> (m,M.filter (\(o,mp2) -> not . M.null $ mp2) mp))
     . M.map (\(m,mp) -> (m,M.map (\(o,mp2) -> (o,M.filter (>n) mp2)) mp))
     . M.filter (\(_,mp) -> not. M.null $ mp)
     . M.map (\(m,mp) -> (m,M.filter ((n <) . fst) mp))
     . M.filter (\(m,mp) -> m > n)
   -- ex. pprint3B . greaterThan3Q2TO 2 . toSQ3TO piDigits $ M.empty

   unionSQ3TO :: Ord a => Seq3TypeOccurrences a -> Seq3TypeOccurrences a -> Seq3TypeOccurrences a
   unionSQ3TO = M.unionWith (\(n,mp2a) (m,mp2b) -> (n+m,unionSQ2TO mp2a mp2b))
   ```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to define a recursive data structure like this:

```
data Trie = Nil | Trie (Map Char (Int, Trie))
```

This allows the show and add functions to be defined recursively.

Here is an implementation. Run `test3` to see an example of how it works.

```
import qualified Data.Map as M
import Text.PrettyPrint
import Data.List

data Trie = Nil | Trie (M.Map Char (Int, Trie))

showTrie :: String -> Trie -> Doc
showTrie _ Nil = empty
showTrie prefix (Trie m) =
  vcat $ 
    do (k,(count,t)) <- M.assocs m
       let prefix' = prefix ++ [k]
       return $
         vcat [ lparen <> char '"' <> text prefix' <> char '"' <> comma <> int count <> rparen
              , nest 4 (showTrie prefix' t)
              ]

-- add an element to a Trie
addTrie :: Trie -> String -> Trie
addTrie t [] = t
addTrie Nil xs = addTrie (Trie M.empty) xs
addTrie (Trie m) (x:xs) = 
  case M.lookup x m of
    Nothing     -> let t' = addTrie Nil xs
                   in Trie $ M.insert x (1,t') m
    Just (c,t)  -> let t' = addTrie t xs
                   in Trie $ M.insert x (c+1,t') m

test1 = 
  let t1 = addTrie Nil "abcd"
      t2 = addTrie t1  "abce"
  in putStrLn $ render $ showTrie "" t2

test2 n str =
  putStrLn $ render $ showTrie "" $
      foldr (flip addTrie) Nil (map (take n) (tails str))

test3 = test2 4 "31415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679821480865132823066470938446095505822317253594081284811174502841027019385211055596446229489549303819644288109756659334461284756"
```

Comment: You don't need a dedicated `Nil` constructor: the empty `Map` will work just as well (and gets rid of the `Nil` / `Trie mempty` redundancy)